# copy/paste data into specific columns using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

i`m new to stackoverflow and python/pandas and i wanted to paste a columns that i copied to another file in a columns without a name, here is the code

```
    import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

folder = "files/Daily_Reports"
df_total = pd.DataFrame()
files = os.listdir(folder)


def main():

    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
            print('loading file {0}.....'.format(file))
            df = pd.read_excel(f'{folder}/{file}')
            print(df["Sales in USD"])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

i just wanted the code to copy a column and paste in another column in a "master file" starting in column c and going until it reads all of the files

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What is the problem with your code? What happens when you run it, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].

Comment: thanks @Robert !!. this code runs perfectly but it doesn`t do what i wanted to.
i expected it to get an entire column from a sheet in excel and copy to another file in another column.

Comment: All that is happening here is you're reading the files in a loop, loading them into a dataframe and doing nothing with that data.. You can't exactly 'paste' with pandas. I think you want to have a main dataframe that you then add columns to from the different files